# Looking for online XSLT transformer

Tags: web-services, web

Looking for web service that download a webpage (we'll provide the URL), normalize it (gets XHTML) and applies XSLT (which sits on another URL we provide). Must support JSONP style result.

Could anyone suggest something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo YQL is the answer: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/.